# How to handle redirected request in Apache HttpClient5?

Tags: java, spring, apache-httpclient-5.x

I am currently migrating our project to the latest version of Spring. Since Spring 6 is using the new Apache HttpClient5, I am struggling to find any kind of replacement for the old removed methods from the `DefaultRedirectStrategy` class:

`protected boolean isRedirectable(String method)`

and

`public HttpUriRequest getRedirect(final HttpRequest request, final HttpResponse response, final HttpContext context) throws ProtocolException`

With HttpClient4 these methods were used to make all request redirectable and reset streams if possible.
I tried to search for any replacement or documentation about it, but unfortunately I could not find anything.

I am happy for each answer :)